# get values from object type data .net

Tags: .net, object-type

Here is my function:

```
   public object GetAnObject()
   {
       return context.ATableEntity.Select(s => new { s.BILDIRIM_ID, s.VERSIYON }).FirstOrDefault();
   }

   var DynamicObject = GetAnObject();

   //DynamicObject looks like; ({BILDIRIM_ID=12345, VERSIYON ="asdasdsad"})
```

I need to get these BILDIRIM_ID and VERSIYON, try to do something like DynamicObject[0] or DynamicObject.VERSIYON. How can I fget these values ?